# Merge two arrays into a Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

My desired outcome is something like this:

```
{date: 12/02/2014, minutes: 36}
```

I'm scraping with Nokogiri using:

```
dates = doc.css('td:nth-child(3)')
minutes = doc.css('td:nth-child(10)')
```

Then I do some filtering and pushing results into arrays:

```
dates.each do |x|
 if x.text.length == 10
     date_array << x.text
 end
end

minutes.each do |x|
 minutes_array << x.text
end
```

How can I zip these two arrays together to create my desired outcome?

i've tried something like this, but it's not quite right (gives me {"2013-10-29"=>"32:14"} )

```
result = Hash[date_array.zip(minutes_array)]
```

or even something like this:

```
 result = Hash[date_array.zip(minutes_array).map {|d, m| {:date => d, :minutes => m}}
```

but i get this error: wrong element type Hash at 163

i've also tinkered with .flatten but to no avail. Can anybody help?

Comment: In that last line of code with `map`, you're missing a right brace `]`.

Comment: Where is your sample HTML demonstrating what you are parsing, or an example of the Array that results from using Nokogiri?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

assuming you have 2 equal length arrays x and y

```
x = [:key1, :key2, :key3]
y =  [:value1, :value2, :value3]
z = {}
x.each_with_index { |key,index| z[key] = y[index] }

puts z

=> {:key1=>:value1, :key2=>:value2, :key3=>:value3}
```

is that what you are looking for?

then maybe this:

```
x = [:key1, :key2, :key3]
y =  [:value1, :value2, :value3]
z = []
x.each_with_index { |key,index| z << { date: key, minutes: y[index]} }



puts   z

{:date=>:key1, :minutes=>:value1}
{:date=>:key2, :minutes=>:value2}
{:date=>:key3, :minutes=>:value3}
```

Comment: the code works as you described, but my desired result would be

{date: 12/02/2014, minutes: 36:12}

whereas now, i am getting:

{"2013-10-29"=>"32:14"}

Comment: so the hash is only 2 entries then date and minutes?

Comment: or do you want an array of hashes [{date: blah, minutes: blah}, {date: blah2, minutes: blahbalh} ] ?

Comment: tried it, got this 

'date_array = []

against_team_array = []
# minutes_array = []
z = []

date_array.each_with_index { |key,index| z << { date: key, minutes: against_team_array[i]} }

puts z

and got nothing

Comment: you should update your question with more code,  for example, it's not clear what against_team_array is.

Answer (score 2):

Stealing from nPn (I can't comment on his answer because I've got no reputation )

Assuming you have

```
x = [ "date1", "date2", "date3"]
y = [ "time1", "time2", "time3"]
```

Then you can do:

```
z = []
x.each_with_index { |k, i|  z << { date: k, time: y[i] }   }
puts z
=> [ { date: "date1", time: "time1" },  
     { date: "date2", time: "time2" },
     { date: "date3", time: "time3" } ]
```

Is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: thanks :-), but not enough to upvote your answer :-(

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to have the same key (date, minutes) for multiple values. You can instead have an array of hash for all those date-minute combos though, with this -

```
date.zip(minutes).reduce([]) { |memo, combo| memo << Hash[*[:date, :minutes].zip(combo).flatten] }
```

Here is how it looks -

```
2.1.5 :035 > date=["10/10,2010","11/10/2010","12/10/2010","13/10/2010","14/10/2010"]
 => ["10/10,2010", "11/10/2010", "12/10/2010", "13/10/2010", "14/10/2010"] 
2.1.5 :036 > minutes = [10,20,30,40,50]
 => [10, 20, 30, 40, 50] 
2.1.5 :037 > date.zip(minutes).reduce([]) { |memo, combo| memo << Hash[*[:date, :minutes].zip(combo).flatten] }
 => [{:date=>"10/10,2010", :minutes=>10}, {:date=>"11/10/2010", :minutes=>20}, {:date=>"12/10/2010", :minutes=>30}, {:date=>"13/10/2010", :minutes=>40}, {:date=>"14/10/2010", :minutes=>50}] 
2.1.5 :038 >
```

Word of caution - you should really use a Struct, and then create an array of that Struct instances, instead of working on arrays of hashes like this.

Comment: thanks for your concise answer! your answer and @npn's answer give me the same result -- I will start using structs.

Answer (score 1):

If

```
dates   = ["12/02/14", "6/03/14"]
minutes = [12, 19]
```

then if I've not misunderstood the question, it's just:

```
dates.zip(minutes).map { |d,m| {date: d, minutes: m} }
  #=> [{:date=>"12/02/14", :minutes=>12}, {:date=>"6/03/14", :minutes=>19}]
```